# Preloading images to use as JLabel icon

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jslider

I want to have a simple `JFrame` with a `JLabel` (to show images as an icon) and a `JSlider` (to switch between 40 images).

When I load the new images on a `StateChange` event of the slider, the program gets very slow, especially when I slide fast.

So I was thinking of preloading the 40 images and replacing them via the slider. Is this smart and possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. We can't help you with specifics at this stage because you haven't given any. Why not simply first try it? If you don't, how will we know what problems you may be having?

Comment: have a look at the `java.awt.MediaTracker` class and `ImageIcon`also uses `MediaTracker` if I am not wrong - so it is pretty simple to preload the images

Comment: Don't load icons directly in event listener. Use `javax.swing.Timer` with a delay instead. So you can avoid loading of non-required images, when user slides quickly (simply cancel the old timer and start a new one).

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you have something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    // other declarations
    private JLabel label;
    // other methods
    public void stateChange(ChangeEvent e) {
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(...)); // here is code to determine name of the icon to load.
                timer = null;
    }
}
```

What you need is to change your code as following:

```
public class MyClass {
    // other declarations
    private JLabel label;
    private Timer timer; // javax.swing.Timer
    // other methods
    public void stateChange(ChangeEvent e) {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.stop();
        }
        timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(...)); // here is code to determine name of the icon to load.
                timer = null;
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```